# Paypal Ipn Notification Url in profile and in Pay request

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using Paypal Sandbox to test some adaptive payments that I'm developing for my website.

I have an IPN listener set up so that I can process when a user of my website executes a payment.

In order to pass a `custom` parameter to the listener, I need to specify the `ipnNotificationUrl` field of the `PayRequest` Object at the time that I send the Pay request `(eg req.setIpnNotificationUrl("[someurl]?custom=[myCustomId]")`

However, in order to get my account to receive IPN's, I also need to enable them in my account profile as well as specify a valid URL for the listener (this time in my paypal account profile).

This leads to two different places where I specify the `ipnNotificationUrl`.
And therefore, my listener gets hit twice every time I need to be notified of some action.

Is this intentional? Am I supposed to process two different notifications for every action? (the Messages received are slightly different - eg: one has an `mc_gross` parameter and the other doesn't, one has a `txn_type` parameter while the other has a `transaction_type` parameter...with different values, etc.)

Or, is there a way to set up my account so that only the address specified in the `PayRequest` Object gets notified?

Thank you.